# Key Error in Pandas while copying a column to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe based on another existing column in the same dataframe and then copy the new column to a different dataframe.

```
df1['column1'] = ''
df1.loc[df['column2'] == 'A', 'column1'] = 'Apple'
df1.loc[df['column2'] == 'B', 'column1'] = 'Ball'
```

I am able to see the new column in the dataframe when printed.
I am trying to create a new column in another dataframe with values from column1 in df1

```
df2['column1'] = df1['column1']
```

But I get the following error:

> File
> "/root/airflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
> line 3621, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 136, in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
> "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 163, in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
> "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
> "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'column1'

Can anyone help with the issue?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code for others to be able to recreate the error. Not enough information provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly augmented version of your code that does what you want (I think):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column2': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], size=10)})
df1['column1'] = ''
df1.loc[df['column2'] == 'A', 'column1'] = 'Apple'
df1.loc[df['column2'] == 'B', 'column1'] = 'Ball'
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': range(10)})
df2['column1'] = df1['column1']
df2
```

I recommend that you inspect your `df1` object immediately prior to your
`df2['column1'] = df1['column1']` line, to verify that it looks as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you add more information it will help to find a problem.
I don't understand.  df2  - Is it existing DataFrame?

I tried to reproduce your mistake and I couldn't.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col1'] = ''
df.loc[df['col2'] == 3, 'column1'] = 'Apple'
df.loc[df['col2'] == 4, 'column1'] = 'Ball'
g = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=g)
df2['column1'] = df['column1']
df2
```

And I got the result:

[image: Result]